# I have a Java Applet working in Eclipse but not working as embedded applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, embedding

What is the step by step process to move from Eclipse to embedding on an HTML page? I have the  tags and the jar file exported but it tells me it can't find a main class. I have tried a few things but to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: What is the "it" that is complaining about the main class? What things have you tried and what specifically were the results?  What are you using to open the HTML page?

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing java applets? Embedded java on the web is all but dead.

Comment: Firefox is complaining about no .class file found when I try to run the HTML file. I have tried the <applet> tags and a separate single .class file and it worked but when I try to use a .class file in a jar file, it won't find it. I'm using Firefox to open.

I'm writing java applets because I wanted to create something that is tangible and visible to others. I guess I should be making Windows or iOS or some other type of app but I know Java best. (I have made Android though)(On a side note, I didn't know embedded java was dead. Why is that?

Comment: *"but it tells me it can't find a main class"*  What is 'it' exactly and copy/paste the message.  *"I'm writing java applets because I wanted to create something that is tangible and visible to others."*  Then use JS+HTML 5 which is usable by a whole lot more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Deploying An Applet In Under 10 Minutes](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deploying_an_applet_in_under) :

- Compile / build your applet's Java code and make sure all class
  files and resources such as images etc. are in a separate directory,
  example build/components.
- Create a jar file containing your applet's
  class files and resources.
- Sign your jar file if the applet needs
  special security permissions, for example, to be launched in a modern JRE with default settings. By default, unsigned code will be blocked.
- Create a JNLP file that describes how your applet
  should be launched.

See also [Deployment Toolkit 101 - Java Tutorials Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deployment_toolkit_101)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Oracle's page on deploying a Java applet:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

I would start with that and if you still have specific problems, come back to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've seen this already but I'll sift through this tutorial just in case. My specific problem is my jar file. Firefox won't read from a jar file and won't find my .class file in my jar file. When I just reference a .class file outside of a jar, it works. That's why I was baffled.